# Implement Three Section header with sticky sections

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, rxjs

I have to implement a 3 section sticky header. The first section is a header part, the second section is a hero component, the 3d part is a subheader. When the user starts to scroll the page, 2nd section (hero component) disappears behind the header. The 3d section sticks to the header. If the user continues scrolling and scrolled 30% of the page, the 3d section also starts to hide behind the header.

I have some questions:
1) How to better organize the code (split the header into components)
2) And how to implement the described logic using Angular 8?

Maybe there are some examples with Angular 2+

I have implemented a subheader that hides the hero part on scroll

HTML

```
<div class="subheader__wrapper">
  <div class="subheader subheader__sticky"
      [ngClass]="getSubheaderClassTop()"
  >

      <div class="row align-middle align-justify subheader-row-height u-grid-full-width">
        <cc-breadcrumb class="columns"></cc-breadcrumb>

        <a *ngIf="!noBackButton" (click)="onBack()"
            id="form-dropdown-back-link"
            class="columns small-1 mos-u-text-size--md mos-u-color-text--white"
          >
          <my-icon size="lg" icon="keyboard_arrow_left" theme="disabled-light" alt="Back"></my-icon>
          <span class="anchor-icon-text-fix">{{ 'subheader.back' | translate }}</span>
        </a>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>

<hero
  *ngIf="isHeroVisible"
  class="mos-c-position--relative"
  [backgroundUrl]="heroImageURL"
  [backgroundImage]="gradient"
  blendMode="multiply"
  backgroundPosition="top"
  flexDirection="row"
  minHeight="192">

  <div *ngIf="!isBlendMode" class="subheader__gradient"></div>
  <div class="subheader__content flex-child-grow">
    <div class="row x-large-row c-position--relative">
      <div class="column medium-8 small-12 u-color-text--white x-large-6">
        <h2 class="o-subheader-2" data-id="subheader">
          {{ heroSubtitle }} {{heroSubtitleDate}}
        </h2>
        <h2 class="mos-o-display-2" data-id="header">
          {{ heroTitle }}
        </h2>
        <hr class="subheader__separator c-hero--separator">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</hero>
```

CSS

```
:host {
  display: block;
}

.subheader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: color(sapphire, 500);
  z-index: 100;

  &-row-height {
    height: 52px;
  }
  &__sticky {
    position: fixed;
  }
  &__gradient {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 100%);
  }
  &__content {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    justify-self: center;

    .subheader__separator {
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }
}

.circle-step-position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

JS

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  NgZone,
  Output,
  ElementRef,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
} from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { pathOr } from 'ramda';
import { AutoUnsubscribe } from '../shared/auto-unsubscribe.decorator';
import { WindowRef } from '../services/api/aot-ref/windowRef';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, distinctUntilChanged, map, throttleTime, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'cc-section-subheader',
  templateUrl: './subheader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subheader.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
@AutoUnsubscribe
export class SubheaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  componentDestroy;
  @Input() subheader: string;
  @Input() header: string;
  @Input() country: string;
  @Input() noBackButton: boolean;
  @Input() heroTitle: string;
  @Input() heroSubtitle: string;
  @Input() heroSubtitleDate: string;
  @Input() heroImageURL: string;

  @Input() isHeroVisible = false;
  @Input() isSummary = false;
  @Input() isFileUpload = false;
  @Input() isValidateData = false;
  @Input() isJobMatch = false;
  @Input() isAggregateValidation = false;

  @Output() back = new EventEmitter<void>();

  adjustSubheader = true;
  lastScroll = 0;
  lastHeight: string;

  isExpanded = false;
  isBlendMode = false;

  constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private window: WindowRef,
    private subheaderElement: ElementRef,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {
    this.isBlendMode = !!('backgroundBlendMode' in document.body.style);
  }

  get areButtonsDisabled() {
    return true;
  }

  get gradient(): string {
    return this.isBlendMode
      ? 'linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, white 100%)'
      : null;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      fromEvent(this.window.nativeWindow, 'scroll')
        .pipe(
        map(() => this.isHeaderVisible()),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroy())
      )
        .subscribe((isHeaderVisible: boolean) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.adjustSubheader = isHeaderVisible;
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
          });
        });
    });

    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      fromEvent(this.window.nativeWindow, 'resize').pipe(
        startWith(null),
        throttleTime(200),
        takeUntil(this.componentDestroy()),
      )
        .subscribe(() => this.updateWrappersHeight());
    });
  }


  /**
   * Since sub-header has position set as fixed it removes the element from the normal document
   * flow. To properly align content under it we need to set sub-header's height equal to
   * sub-header.
   */
  updateWrappersHeight(): void {
    const el = this.subheaderElement.nativeElement;
    const headerHeight = this.window.nativeWindow.getComputedStyle(el.querySelector('.subheader')).height;

    if (headerHeight !== this.lastHeight) {
      this.lastHeight = headerHeight;

      el.querySelector('.subheader__wrapper').style.height = this.lastHeight;
    }
  }

  onBack() {
    this.back.emit();
  }

  getHtmlElementOffset(element: HTMLElement, offset = 0): number {
    if (!element.offsetParent) {
      return offset;
    }
    return this.getHtmlElementOffset(
      element.offsetParent as HTMLElement,
      offset + pathOr(0, ['offsetParent', 'offsetTop'], element),
    );
  }

  getElementOffset(element: ElementRef): number {
    if (!element) {
      return 0;
    }
    return this.getHtmlElementOffset(
      element.nativeElement,
      element.nativeElement.offsetTop,
    );
  }

  isHeaderVisible() {
    const scrollTop = this.window.nativeWindow.pageYOffset;
    const down = scrollTop > this.lastScroll;
    const top = this.getElementOffset(this.subheaderElement);
    this.lastScroll = scrollTop;
    return scrollTop <= top;
  }

  getSubheaderClassTop(): string {
    return this.adjustSubheader
      ? ''
      : 'subheader__sticky--fixed-to-top';
  }
}
```